# Building a support chat system using socket io

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io

I'm trying to build a support chat system will allow a user to chat with a bot with pre-set prompts, if the bot is unable to solve the query it will handover the conversation to an agent till the issue is resolved. Since the order id is unique, I want a way to create rooms with the orderID that syncs the history with mongodb and pushes the updates once the user reconnects or whenever the user wants support on the same order. I'm new to nodejs and I have no clue how to handle something like this. FYI the front end is in flutter and the model/mongoose schema for messages is as follows:

```
class ChatMessage {
    late final String content; // text message content
    late final DateTime dateTime;
    late final String orderId; // order in which there is issue
    late final List<String>? choices; // default null
    late final String sender; // contains support agent id or bot id
    late final bool promptImage; // default false
}
```

How do I make sure that the messages exchanged are kept in that specific chat room of that orderId. I did try to implement it, but during testing everyone in all the rooms started getting the messages. Is there any similar open source project I can refer to?

PS: The bot is just a bunch of if-else statements right now since the user can select the options from the prompt and if that does not match, the conversation moves on to agent anyway (for now).